# Copy all filtered data from one worksheet into new workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble finding a surefire to copy only visible cells from one worksheet into a new workbook. My initial workbook is filtered. Something along the lines of:

```
Sub RangeToNew()

    Dim newBook as Workbook
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
        Before:=newBook.Worksheets(1)

End Sub
```

This doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to set the SpecialCells range to a Range object first, then do your copy.  Try this:

```
Sub rangeToNew_Try2()
    Dim newBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim rng As Excel.Range

    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    rng.Copy newBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: This good and looks as though it will work. One thing is stopping it for my case only. I am using Office 2007 and the original file is a .xlsm. I get the error: 

1004 Error Description = Excel cannot insert the sheets into the destination workbook, because it contains fewer rows and columns than the source workbook. To move or copy the data to the destination workbook, you can select the data, and then use the Copy and Paste commands to insert it into the sheets of another workbook.

Comment: There are > 1 million rows in my first book, only 65k in the created ones.